Option in Nx to convert .eslintrc.json to eslint.config.mjs i.e ES module file using @nx/eslint:convert-to-flat-config generator
I have a Monorepo based project setup with Nx and we are updating ESLint from 8.57.0 to 9.8.0. Nx do provides a generator(@nx/eslint:convert-to-flat-config) to automatically transform eslintrc.json to eslint.config.js but I would prefer ES module over cjs filetype.

Does the said generator has option to transform to .mjs?
What configuration changes would I need to make to use eslint.config.mjs over eslint.config.js

I looked at the documentations to help with correct transformation but it is short and concise and doesn't include reference to transforming to .mjs. I would expected a resource,example or a command option of how to convert .eslintrc.json to eslint.config.mjs via Nx.
